# How to retrieve encrypted data in php?

Tags: php

Code is given below

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name1=$_POST["name1"];
        //echo "$name1";
        $name2=$_POST["name2"];
        $email=$_POST["email"];
        $phone=$_POST["phone"];
        $comment=$_POST["comment"];
        $gender=$_POST["gender"];
        $age=$_POST["age1"];
        $date=$_POST["date"];
        $att_date = date("y-m-d",strtotime($_POST["date"])); 

    if($name1 !='' || $email !=''){
                    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_card(fname, lname, email, phone, comment, gender, age, joindate) values(MD5('".$name1."'), MD5('".$name2."'), MD5('".$email."'),    MD5('".$phone."') , '$comment', '$gender','$age', '$att_date')");
                    //echo $query;                                                                                                 encrypt('".$_POST['passwd']."')
                    echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span><br>";

               }else 
                {

                }

    }
```

Comment: help me how to tetrive it:                                                                         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  tb_card ");
  if(! $result )
 {
   die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
 }

Comment: Are you retrieving or submitting data

Comment: i want to retive it.. i already submited into database ... and my job is retrive in original plain text in browser side

Comment: The data you are submitting is not the kind of data typically encrypted with hashing algorithms. I would simply suggest removing the md5 to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

As md5 is a hash algrotythm it could not be decoded. Hash values have a property called disposable property. As of this it is "one-way". They could be compared and so you could see if user input is the same when hashed as the already hashed ones in the database. But use not md5 for password hashes as md5 is vulnerable and there exists many rainbowtables for this hash algorythm.

You need for example mcrypt [mcrypt PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) to do what you want.

Comment: read the manual and try it for yourself first. When you then got questions on mcrypt post it.

Comment: then post your tried code and where it fails or what errors you got. then i would do my best to help

Comment: This is a support community, not a request community. Note that if you don't show any attempt at writing the code yourself or researching, people here will not hand it to you on a silver platter.

Comment: thanx i got solution.. then how to edit this data in text fields.........

Answer (score 0):

sadly, you can't retrive md5 encrypted data.
if have to, try

```
function string2secret($str)
{
 $key = "123";
 $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES,'','ecb','');
 $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
 $ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);

 $key = substr(md5($key), 0, $ks);
 mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
 $secret = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);
 mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
 mcrypt_module_close($td);
 return $secret;
}

function secret2string($sec)
{
 $key = "123";
 $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES,'','ecb','');
 $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
 $ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);

 $key = substr(md5($key), 0, $ks);
 mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
 $string = mdecrypt_generic($td, $sec);
 mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
 mcrypt_module_close($td);
 return trim($string);
}

echo secret2string(string2secret("11111111111111111"));
echo string2secret("11111111111111111");

mcrypt PHP extension is need
```

Comment: how to edit the decrypted fields???

Comment: to use `string2secret()` to encrypt, instead of  `MD5()` in SQL when inserting into _DB_, and use `secret2string()` to decrypt, then you get original string. the only variable you should modify is `$key` if you want.

Comment: $test = mysql_fetch_array($result); $secret_key = "This is my secret key";

 // Create the initialization vector for added security.
 $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
 $fname1=$test['fname'];
 
 //  echo $fname1;
    $asa = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $fname1, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

Comment: how to tetrive it? in original text form in edit form <table>
 <tr>
  <td>Fisrtname:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name1" value="<?php echo $fname1 ?>"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Lastname:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name2" value="<?php echo $lname ?>"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>phone:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone ?>"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Email:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="save" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is a one-way hashing mechanism. It cannot be reversed by way of simple programming such as `unmd5($string)` or the likes. The only way to 'decode' the data in the database is via use of what is known as a rainbow table.

Rainbow tables compare the hashed string (your data) to a list of pre-existing `md5()` hashs to determine which it matchs. If it hits a match it will use the plain-text item in the same row to display a message.

This isn't a viable solution for what you want to do. If you want to recall data you will need to use a custom encoding algorithm (using str_replace() or the likes) or store as plaintext.

The data you are submitting is not the kind of data typically encrypted with hashing algorithms. I would simply suggest removing the md5 to resolve your issue.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_card  WHERE id='$id'");
if (!$result) 
  {
    die("Error: Data not found..");
  }
  
//print_r($result['lname']); 
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: ok thanks.......how to show original text form if and only if i click on edit button............

Comment: How to retrive encrypted data in php? [closed]